# First order separable differential equation modeling

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> There are $2000$ mice in a field. At time $t$ hrs, $x$ mice are infected with a disease. The rate of increase of the number of mice infected is proportional to the product of the mice infected and number of mice not infected. Initially $500$ mice are infected and the disease is spreading at a rate of $50$ mice per hour. Find how long it takes for $1900$ mice to be infected? Solve the differential equation in the form $t =f(x)$.

The question says $dx/dt = k(x)(2000-x)$ this is a separable differential equation solving the differential equation gives $\ln(x) - \ln(2000-x) = 2000kt + c$ further simplify to $\ln(x/(2000-x))= 2000kt + c$ using the initial conditions $x=500 at t=0 c = \ln(1/3)$ hence $\ln(3x/(2000-x)) = 2000kt$. Using the information that after $1$ hour, $550$ mice are infected $k = (1/2000)\cdot\ln(33/29)$ and then solving for $t$ and then substituting $x = 1900$ to solve for $t = 31.3$ hrs. However, the answer is $30.3$ hrs to $3$ S.F. Have I found the constant k wrongly?

Comment: Information says that $\frac{dx}{dt} = 50$ when $t = 0$, not that the number of infected has increased by 50 in the first hour.

Comment: Then what x value should I take to find constant k from 50 = k(x)(2000-x)?

Comment: What is the initial value of x?

Comment: By the question it is 500

Comment: Yes, so put that in your comment formula and find k.

Comment: Yeah that works